# Most efficient method of matching two individual nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to match two specific nodes from rows in a CSV. Here is a chunk from an example CSV: 
[Example csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqNaK.png)

Basically, I need to connect each pair of names. Is it better for my cypher query to be like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file.csv" AS row 
MATCH (P1:Person {name:row.name1}),(P2:Person {name:row.name2}) 
CREATE (P1)-[:knows]-(P2)
```

or this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file.csv" AS row 
MATCH (P1:Person),(P2:Person) WHERE P1.name = row.name1 AND P2.name = row.name2 
CREATE (P1)-[:knows]-(P2)
```

They both seem to work equally well on very small (~100 node) data, but which will be faster on very large amounts of data? Is there a significant difference?

Comment: They are almost certainly identical but you can see for yourself using `PROFILE`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the plans emitted are identical. For importing large amounts of data, having an index on your label and lookup property is a must, as is using periodic commit for LOAD CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look:

Load a initial data set:

```
CREATE (:Person {name:'Jon'})
CREATE (:Person {name:'Doe'})
```

The `PROFILE` result of the queries

```
PROFILE MATCH (person:Person {name:'Jon'}) RETURN person
```

and

```
PROFILE MATCH (person:Person) WHERE person.name='Jon' RETURN person
```

are the same:

[image: PROFILE result]

That is: the two queries are exactly the same at execution time. Both queries will be trasnformed to the same execution plan. Has no difference between these queries running over small or large amounts of data.